# awk - how to exclude private ipaddress

Tags: awk

With netstat -ant result

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q   Local Address         Foreign Address         State
tcp    0      0       192.168.200.14:80     192.168.200.14:12345    TIME_WAIT
tcp    0      0       192.168.200.14:80     53.54.56.56:54321       TIME_WAIT
tcp    0      0       ::1:80                ::1:25195               TIME_WAIT
```

I want to summary number of TIME_WAIT connection from outside ip address only (exclude 127.0.0.1, 192.168.x.x, some local ip address, ipv6).

Please help me with awk command, now I'm using :

```
netstat -nat |awk '/TIME_WAIT/&&/:80/' | wc -l
```

summary all TIME_WAIT connections on port 80

```
netstat -nat |awk '/TIME_WAIT/&&/:80/{split($5,a,":");b[a[1] FS $6]++}END{for (i in b) print b[i],i}'
```

summary TIME_WAIT connection on port 80 per ip address.
Thank you very much.

Comment: please edit your Q to include your required output, given the sample input you have very wisely included. Use four spaces at the front of each line so the formatting is appropriate. Good luck.

Comment: Honestly, I'd do this: `netstat -ant | grep -v '127\.0\.0\.1` | grep -v '192\.168\.' | awk...`

Comment: Hi shellter,
In above example the command 
<code>netstat -nat |awk '/TIME_WAIT/&&/:80/' | wc -l</code> will result 3
I want it result 1 cause I want to summary number of TIME_WAIT connection from outside ip address only
grep -v seems work good for me.

Comment: Please provide a broader example with the desired output.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer that chain of pipes and greps and awk you posted in your comment is equivalent to just one awk command: `netstat -ant | awk '!/127\.0\.0\.1|192\.168\./'`

Comment: @EdMorton Completely fair. :)  I'm a bit of a pipeline nut sometimes. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide any expected output and your sample input is missing a lot and your description is lacking a lot of critical information so this is very much a guess but maybe this is what you're looking for or close to it:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    targetPort = 80
    skipIps = "127.0.0.1 192.168.x.x"
    gsub(/[.]/,"[.]",skipIps)
    gsub(/x/,"[[:digit:]]+",skipIps)
    gsub(/ +/,"|",skipIps)
    skipIps = "^("skipIps")$"
}
{
    split($4,addr,/:/)
    localIp   = addr[1]
    localPort = addr[2]

    split($5,addr,/:/)
    foreignIp   = addr[1]
    foreignPort = addr[2]
}
(foreignIp !~ skipIps) (localPort == targetPort) && /TIME_WAIT/ { cnt++ }
END { print cnt }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
3
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there

```
$ ... | awk '/TIME_WAIT/ 
           && $5 !~ /^127\.0\.0\.1/ 
           && $5 !~ /^192\.168/ {split($5,ip,":");
                                 a[ip[1]]++;
                                 sum++} 
                             END{for(k in a) 
                                    print k,a[k]; 
                                 print "============== ====";
                                 print "Total: ",sum}' | column -t
```